# Data INSERTS into a particular table on local test server but WILL NOT INSERT on the live site

Tags: mysql, database, insert

As the title says, works perfect on my local WAMP test server. Same PHP version installed however mysql on local test server is 5.6.12 and the live mysql version is 5.6.39.  All other inserts and tables on the live site work except one I had an issue with until I signed into the site under a different user and it worked under their profile.  Not having such luck with this last one. Waited a day a it's not inserting into the table under any profile. Also I confirmed its pulling the data properly by using echo statements at the end of the script.  So its got the data but refuses to insert into the database table on the live site.  Any help or ideas is greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
$db->Query("INSERT INTO `ysub` (user, url, title, y_av, max_clicks, daily_clicks, cpc, country, sex) VALUES('".$data['id']."', '".$yt_url."', '".$url."', '".$yt_image."', '".$max_clicks."', '".$daily_clicks."', '".$cpc."', '".$country."', '".$gender."') ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the error function after the query line to see if an error is being caught.

```
$db->query('INSERT INTO...');
echo $db->errorInfo();
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion however it just returned a blank, empty page after adding echo $db->errorInfo();

Comment: You using PDO? The blank page would indicate ->errorInfo() isn't a function available to $db. Whatever db connector you are using should have something similar as errorInfo.